# How do I add attributes to CSS in theme.info?

Tags: theming

I'm try to add a stylesheet switcher.  This requires the following CSS files to be included on the site.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles1.css" title="styles1" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css" title="styles2" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles3.css" title="styles3" media="screen" />
```

theme.info reference some CSS files. How can I a *rel* and *title* attributes?

```
stylesheets[all][] = common/css/small.css
stylesheets[all][] = common/css/medium.css
stylesheets[all][] = common/css/large.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Drupal will use CSS aggregation (and doesn't have support for adding extra attributes via the info file or `drupal_add_css`), you will have to print out the style sheets yourself. This can be done with theme functions or by creating the markup in the `html.tpl.php`